# How to show user e-mail in Drupal 5.x profile (nodeprofile)?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-5

The email field in user profiles in Drupal is as far as i understand not ment to be shown (for good and obvoius reasons).

But I still need to know how to show user e-mail in Drupal 5.x profile (nodeprofile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the theme_user_profile hook (add the function to your template.php located at your current theme folder), like this:

```
function <your_theme_name>_user_profile($account, $fields) {
  // adding the email field to profile
  $email = array();
  $email["value"] =  check_plain($account->mail);
  $fields["email"][0] = $email;
  // end of adding the email field

  // the rest of the default profile hook taken from http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_user_profile/5
  $output = '<div class="profile">';
  $output .= theme('user_picture', $account);
  foreach ($fields as $category => $items) {
    if (strlen($category) > 0) {
      $output .= '<h2 class="title">'. check_plain($category) .'</h2>';
    }
    $output .= '<dl>';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      if (isset($item['title'])) {
        $output .= '<dt class="'. $item['class'] .'">'. $item['title'] .'</dt>';
      }
      $output .= '<dd class="'. $item['class'] .'">'. $item['value'] .'</dd>';
    }
    $output .= '</dl>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

**Update.**  Sorry, didn't notice that you're using nodeprofile module.  I've never used it, but am pretty sure the email can be shown the similar way

Answer (score 3):

Add an email CCK field to your node profile CCK type.

For more details, refer to the [Email Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/email) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Features:
>
> - validation of emails
> - turns addresses into mailto links
> - encryption of email addresses
> - contact form (see Display settings)
> - provides Tokens (for D 7.x: use Entity tokens from the Entity API)
> - exposes fields to Views
> - can be used with Rules
> - Panels Integration

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough . But I wanted to show the email the users registered their account with, and not just add another email-field.

Comment: Than may be panels can help you, it has option to show user profile fields in block.

Answer (score 0):

Look under $user than.

```
global $user;
// You can use dsm with the devel module instead of print_r
print_r($user);
```

You can work with this module also http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan?